# Installing R server on Amazon Linux release 2 (karoo)

Tags: linux

I am trying to add R-server to a server which already has R installed. I noticed that there isn't a whole lot of documentation on getting R-Server to run on awsLinux2 in general. Using a lot of searching and putting Centos/RHEL notes together I though I was getting close after installing from a rpm. However I am getting these two errors which preventing the service from starting.

```
r-server rserver[11181]: /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver: /lib64/libpq.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver)
r-server rserver[11181]: /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver)
```

I haven't found anything specific about these items and how to address them. Any guidance would be helpful.

UPDATE 1: Addressing libpq

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install postgresql14
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what happed to this server. I rebuilt with a fresh image and ran though the centos7 install commands from rstudio.org and it's running fine.

I'm going to kill the old one after transferring files.